# Update the previous element of list in a loop based on a condition

Tags: python, list

I am trying clean the names of the list.

```
results = []
mylist = ['jellyfish','jellyish','jellyish','smellyfish']

#convert to unicode
mylist = [unicode(i) for i in mylist]

for i, j in enumerate(mylist):
    current = mylist[i] 
    previous = mylist[i-1]
    current_score = jf.jaro_winkler(current, previous)
    if(current_score > 0.96):
        current=previous
    print current, current_score
```

I get the following results:

- jellyfish 0.896296296296
- jellyfish 0.977777777778
- **jellyish 1.0**
- smellyfish 0.858333333333

The first two records is what i want, but I need jellyish to be changed to jellyfish as well.

Expected results should be..

- jellyfish 0.896296296296
- jellyfish 0.977777777778
- **jellyfish 0.977777777778**
- smellyfish 0.858333333333

Comment: Not sure what this is. What is a jaro winkler?

Comment: this is a method under jellyfish to compare string similarity, that gives the number for current_score.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on what needs to be changed - you're currently doing `current = previous` which does nothing but reassign the variable `current` to another object.

What you need to do is actually *update* the list in place. You're already iterating over the indices, so you'll just need to make a small change.

```
mylist = ['jellyfish', 'jellyish', 'jellyish', 'smellyfish']

for i, v in enumerate(mylist[1:], 1):
    p, c = mylist[i - 1], v
    if jf.jaro_winkler(p, c) > .96:
        mylist[i] = p
```

Answer (score 0):

The values in the original list are not being updated. You need to do it by adding the following line -

```
previous = mylist[i-1]
current_score = jf.jaro_winkler(current, previous)
if (current_score > 0.96):
    mylist[i] = mylist[i-1]
    current = previous
```